# Does D3.js support native mobile applications?

Tags: javascript, mobile, d3.js

I have found some questions regarding support of D3 for creating mobile applications viewed using the mobile browser. I would like to know if there is support from D3 in creating a native mobile application (for example on an Android device)?

If there isn't support for a native mobile application, what would be the best way to implement a native-like application on a mobile device using D3?

Otherwise, is there an alternative to D3 to create an native interactive visualisation application on a mobile device?

Thanks!

Comment: I just went to the website on my android device, clicked on some sample, and it works for me™. Also what do you mean by _native_? Using d3.js in the native browser?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. By native I mean creating for example an Android app i.e. not using the browser.

Comment: As far as i know d3.js is JavaScript ( with DOM ) only so I guess your best bet for making it into an app would be something like PhoneGap, i'm no Android developer though

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[D3](http://d3js.org/) is a library geared towards manipulating data and rendering it into an html DOM –– either via SVG, or straight up divs or perhaps a canvas. Of course there also needs to be a JavaScript engine that can run the code. Browsers provide all those things; native apps provide none of them out of the box.

However, there are ways to build native apps that wrap a javascript engine and DOM. [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) is a commonly used framework for doing so. It essentially lets you develop as if things are going to run in a browser, but they're packaged into a native app. There's a performance hit to that: It won't run as fast as a native app, and often not even as fast as the same code would run in a mobile browser. But from the user's perspective, it's installed and launched just like any native app.

That's AFAIK the only way to use d3 in a native app.

Comment: It doesn't have to come down to PhoneGap. D3 code works in ordinary `WebView` as well.

Comment: Right. WebView is how PhoneGap does its thing –– without requiring much knowledge about what a WebView is or how to get one going.